# How to manipulate regex named capturing groups

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use a capture group to replace data with itself, plus a manipulation to a number in it. This is the text to work on:

```
firstGroup1
firstGroup33
```

My goal is to replace any number of group with itself + 1 to get, for example:

```
firstGroup2
firstGroup34
```

This currently is the code to display the two different capture groups:

```
data = data.replace(/(firstGroup)([1])/gms, '$1 $2')
```

and this is a failed attempt to do what I want, for sakes of understanding the question:

```
data = data.replace(/(firstGroup)([1])/gms, '$1' + $2+1
```

How can I perform this number addition in nodeJS javascript? thank you!

**example 2:**

text:

```
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 2
```

failed code:

```
data = data.replace(/(constructor \<init\>[(][)]V.............)(..)/gms, (_, first, num) => first + (Number(num) + 1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any *named* capturing groups here, only plain capturing groups - use a replacer function that replaces with the first captured group, concatenated with the second capturing group cast to a number plus 1:

```js
const data = `firstGroup1
firstGroup33`;

const result = data.replace(
  /(firstGroup)(\d+)/g,
  (_, first, num) => first + (Number(num) + 1)
);
console.log(result);
```

Because you aren't using the `.` to match spaces anywhere in the pattern, there's no need for the `s` modifier, nor are you using `^` or `$`, so no need for the `m` modifier either.

(A named capturing group looks something like:

```js
const str = 'foo bar';
const match = str.match(/foo (?<whatComesAfterFoo>\S+)/);
console.log(match.groups.whatComesAfterFoo);
```

)

Comment: Great answer and very informative! :)

Could you explain the _,first,num part? why do we use _?

Comment: The first argument of the replacer function is the full match, which we don't need, so I named it `_`. Second argument is first captured group, third argument is second captured group.

Comment: Any idea why the example I added (example 2) doesn't work in your method?

Comment: You're ending the pattern with `(..)`, but there's only one digit there. Maybe replace with `(\d+)` instead, to match 1 or more digits? https://regex101.com/r/fc3hyM/1

Comment: I've tried it, and for me it also works in regexr101, but for some reason it doesn't match this way in the replace code. I think its because of the line difference? I am lost.

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/kfp7085o/ all I did was replace the `(..)` with `(\d+)`